# Как открыть окно расширения по событию

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Всем привет. Моё расширение получает запросы и при получении одного из них я хочу чтобы открывалось само расширение (т.е. как будто пользователь сам кликнул по иконке расширения). Как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это невозможно легальными средствами, ибо сказано было [Знающими](http://blog.chromium.org/):

> The philosophy for browser and page action popups is that they must be
>   triggered by user action. Our suggestion is to use the new html
>   notifications feature...

О чём сказано выше (примерно...):

> Мы, The Chromium dev, считаем, что вызов окон расширений может быть вызван только действиями пользователя.
>   Если сильно надо вызвать программно - используйте [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/notification).

---

Но есть полумера - воспользоватся разрешением `tabs` в манифесте и кодом:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url:"popup.html"});
```

Будет открыта новая вкладка с окном Вашего расширения.